# Full Background Gradient Cover with No Repeat

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I have a CSS background gradient, which when the page height fills the browser window seems to repeat again. I have tried the usual "no-repeat", "cover" and "contain options with no joy.

How can I get the background cover to always fill the screen, regardless of whether I have a long or short page?

```
{
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 85% 1%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 0%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 96%, transparent 96%, transparent 100%), radial-gradient(circle at 14% 15%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 0%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 1%, transparent 1%, transparent 100%), radial-gradient(circle at 60% 90%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 0%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 100%), radial-gradient(circle at 79% 7%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 0%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 78%, transparent 78%, transparent 100%), radial-gradient(circle at 55% 65%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 0%, hsla(190, 0%, 93%, 0.05) 52%, transparent 52%, transparent 100%), linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(37, 56, 222), rgb(96, 189, 244));
}
```

Here is is in action in a short page, with no scrolling required and a longer page requiring scrolling

https://boring-saha-ba54d1.netlify.app/

https://pedantic-ritchie-faf62a.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```